# Understanding complex jQuery Validation rules

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a validate method for a form that is very complex, and was written by a front end developer before me.  There is a main question with two sub questions, and if the main one is toggled, at least on subquestion must be toggled. Any subquestion that is toggled must have a comment. I must make changes to it, but am first trying to understand how it works. I was hoping someone can answer the following questions on this:

1. For the functions added with addMethod, is this a custom rule?  Is that why in rules the function is listed and set to "true"?
2. What is the defaultInvlid function for on each of the rules?  I see that it returns true/false. What is the effect of returning true?
3. Why are functions included under messages?  Does this just mean if the functions return true, display that message?

```
$("#form1").validate({
            errorLabelContainer: $("#form-error"),
            rules: {

                //sub fields question 1
                'report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_SUB_missing_parts_comment': {
                    required: '#report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_SUB_missing_parts_not_acceptable:checked',
                    report1subfields: true,
                    defaultInvalid: {
                        depends: function (element) {
                            return $('#report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_SUB_missing_parts_not_acceptable').is(':checked') ? true : false;
                        }
                    }
                },

                'report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_SUB_other_issues_comment': {
                    required: '#report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_SUB_other_issues_not_acceptable:checked',
                    report1subfields: true,
                    defaultInvalid: {
                        depends: function (element) {
                            return $('#report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_SUB_other_issues_not_acceptable').is(':checked') ? true : false;
                        }
                    }
                }

            },
            focusInvalid: false,
            messages: {
                'report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_SUB_missing_parts_comment': {
                    defaultInvalid: "Are there missing parts?",
                    report1subfields: "Did You Receive The Product As Ordered? > At least one subquestion is mandatory."
                },
                'report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_SUB_other_issues_comment': {
                    defaultInvalid: "Are there other issues with your order?",
                    report1subfields: "Did You Receive The Product As Ordered? > At least one subquestion is mandatory."
                }
            },

            submitHandler: function (form) {

                //SUBMIT

            },

            invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
                showFormError(validator);
            }
}).settings.ignore = [];
```

**HTML**

```
                    <div id="question-form-wrapper">

                            <div id="form-error" style="display: none"></div>

                            <div class="questions-form" id="report-questions-form">

                                <div class="question question-textarea has-subquestions" runat="server" id="div0001_00" style="display:none;">
                                    <div class="question-intro clearfix">
                                        <h2 id="QuestionText0001_00" runat="server">Did You Receive The Product As Ordered?</h2>

                                        <div class="no-yes answer-acceptable">
                                            <div class="no"><label class="label-1" for="report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_not_acceptable">Not Acceptable</label></div>
                                            <a href="#" class="toggle" runat="server" id="report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_link"></a>
                                            <div class="yes"><label class="label-2" for="report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_acceptable">Acceptable</label></div>
                                            <label class="universal-label"></label>

                                            <input type="radio" id="report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_not_acceptable" name="report-question-ID-product-received-as-ordered" value="0" runat="server">
                                            <input type="radio" id="report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_acceptable" name="report-question-ID-product-received-as-ordered" value="1" checked="true" runat="server">

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="question-content">
                                        <div class="question-content-inner clearfix">

                                          <div class="sub-questions-list">

                                                <div class="sub-question sub-question-textarea" runat="server" id="div0001_01" style="display:none;">
                                                    <div class="sub-question-intro clearfix">
                                                        <h3 id="QuestionText0001_01" runat="server">Are there missing parts?</h3>

                                                        <div class="yes-no answer-acceptable">
                                                            <div class="yes"><label class="label-1" for="report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_SUB_missing_parts_not_acceptable">Yes</label></div>
                                                            <a href="#" class="toggle" runat="server" id="report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_SUB_missing_parts_link"></a>
                                                            <div class="no"><label class="label-2" for="report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_SUB_missing_parts_acceptable">No</label></div>
                                                            <label class="universal-label"></label>

                                                            <input type="radio" id="report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_SUB_missing_parts_not_acceptable" name="report-question-ID-product-received-as-ordered-SUB-missing-parts" value="1" runat="server">
                                                            <input type="radio" id="report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_SUB_missing_parts_acceptable" name="report-question-ID-product-received-as-ordered-SUB-missing-parts" value="0" checked="true" runat="server">

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="sub-question-content">
                                                        <div class="sub-question-content-inner clearfix">

                                                            <div class="rounded-corners">
                                                                <div class="rounded-corners-inner clearfix">                        
                                                                    <div class="comment-wrapper">
                                                                      <textarea class="comment-for-question" cols="10" rows="20" name="report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_SUB_missing_parts_comment" id="report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_SUB_missing_parts_comment" runat="server">Please provide comments. Up to 5 photos can be attached.</textarea>
                                                                    </div>

                                                                    <div class="upload-photos clearfix" runat="server">

                                                                        <div class="upload-photos-add" id="Q0001_01" runat="server">
                                                                            <asp:AjaxFileUpload EnableViewState="false" ID="AjaxFileUpload1" ContextKeys="0001.01" runat="server" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,png" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload_UploadComplete" OnClientUploadComplete="onClientUploadComplete" OnClientUploadCompleteAll="onClientUploadCompleteAll" OnClientUploadStart="onClientUploadStart" OnClientUploadError="onClientUploadError"></asp:AjaxFileUpload>
                                                                        </div>

                                                                        <div class="upload-photos-list">
                                                                            <div class="upload-photos-list-inner clearfix" runat="server" id="divUploadListDynamic0001_01">
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>

                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="sub-question sub-question-textarea" runat="server" id="div0001_02" style="display:none;">
                                                    <div class="sub-question-intro clearfix">
                                                        <h3 id="QuestionText0001_02" runat="server">Are there other issues with your order?</h3>

                                                        <div class="yes-no answer-acceptable">
                                                            <div class="yes"><label class="label-1" for="report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_SUB_other_issues_not_acceptable">Yes</label></div>
                                                            <a href="#" class="toggle" runat="server" id="report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_SUB_other_issues_link"></a>
                                                            <div class="no"><label class="label-2" for="report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_SUB_other_issues_acceptable">No</label></div>
                                                            <label class="universal-label"></label>

                                                            <input type="radio" id="report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_SUB_other_issues_not_acceptable" name="report-question-ID-product-received-as-ordered-SUB-other-issues" value="1" runat="server">
                                                            <input type="radio" id="report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_SUB_other_issues_acceptable" name="report-question-ID-product-received-as-ordered-SUB-other-issues" value="0" checked="true" runat="server">

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="sub-question-content">
                                                        <div class="sub-question-content-inner clearfix">

                                                            <div class="rounded-corners">
                                                                <div class="rounded-corners-inner clearfix">                        
                                                                    <div class="comment-wrapper">
                                                                      <textarea class="comment-for-question" cols="10" rows="20" name="report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_SUB_other_issues_comment" id="report_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_SUB_other_issues_comment" runat="server">Please provide comments. Up to 5 photos can be attached.</textarea>
                                                                    </div>

                                                                    <div class="upload-photos clearfix" runat="server">

                                                                        <div class="upload-photos-add" id="Q0001_02" runat="server">
                                                                            <asp:AjaxFileUpload EnableViewState="false" ID="AjaxFileUpload2" ContextKeys="0001.02" runat="server" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,png" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload_UploadComplete" OnClientUploadComplete="onClientUploadComplete" OnClientUploadCompleteAll="onClientUploadCompleteAll" OnClientUploadStart="onClientUploadStart" OnClientUploadError="onClientUploadError"></asp:AjaxFileUpload>
                                                                        </div>

                                                                        <div class="upload-photos-list">
                                                                            <div class="upload-photos-list-inner clearfix" runat="server" id="divUploadListDynamic0001_02">
                                                                            </div>                                                                              
                                                                        </div>

                                                                    </div>                                                              

                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                          </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="actions">
                                    <input type="image" src="assets/images/css/button-next-red.png" alt="Next" runat="server" id="btnNext">
                                </div>

                            </div><!-- #report-questions-form -->                           
                    </div><!-- #question-form-wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. For the functions added with `addMethod`, is this a custom rule? Is that why in rules the function is listed and set to "true"?

I don't see `.addMethod()` used anywhere in your OP.

However, yes, [the `.addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/?s=addmethod) is used for *creating* a custom rule (a.k.a. "method").  Setting it to `true` declares it on this field, no different than setting any other rule to `true`.

---

> 2. What is the `defaultInvalid` function for on each of the rules? I see that it returns true/false. What is the effect of returning true?

`defaultInvalid` is a custom method and since I cannot see your corresponding `.addMethod('defaultInvalid', ...)`, I cannot tell you what it does.  However, `true` means you want the rule in effect for this field and `false` means you don't.

Your `id` and `name` values are ridiculously long, so I'm clipping them for my answer...

```
defaultInvalid: {
    depends: function (element) {
        return $('#yourRadioID').is(':checked') ? true : false;
    }
}
```

[The `depends` property is part of the `rules` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#rules).  It allows you to set conditions for when rules are in effect.

In your case, if the targeted radio element is checked by the user, then apply the `defaultInvalid` rule to the field, otherwise not.

In other words, when the targeted radio is checked, it would have this effect...

```
defaultInvalid: true // <- rule is enabled for this field
```

And when the targeted radio is UN-checked, it would have this effect...

```
defaultInvalid: false // <- rule is disabled for this field
```

---

> 3. Why are functions included under messages? Does this just mean if the functions return true, display that message?

**There are no functions included in *your* `messages` option**.  This is just where your custom error messages are defined.

*Everything* inside the `.validate()` method is an "object literal"... a comma separated list of `key:value` pairs surrounded by braces.  A `value` is allowed to be another object literal or a function.  (`key`'s and allowed `value`'s are as per the plugin's author.)

```
messages: {
    yourField1: { // <- the input NAME attribute
        required: "you must fill this out", // <- custom message for this required rule.
        phoneUS: "must be a phone"  // <- custom message for this phoneUS rule.
    },
    yourField2: { // <- the input NAME attribute
        required: "this is required", // <- custom message for this required rule.
        number: "must be a number"  // <- custom message for this number rule.
    }
},
```

---

There is no good reason to attach the `ignore` option to the end of `.validate()` using `.settings` like this...

```
$("#form1").validate({ ... }).settings.ignore = [];
```

It's very sloppy coding because it's disparate from the rest of your options and it unnecessarily calls another method.

For simplification, just declare the `ignore` option like any other...

```
$("#form1").validate({
    ignore: [],  // <- inside validate() with your other options
    errorLabelContainer: $("#form-error"),
    rules: {
        ....
    },
    // your other options
});
```

---

- **I strongly suggest that you review the information on [the SO Tag Wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) for basic usage of the jQuery Validate plugin.**
- **Also refer to [the official website](http://jqueryvalidation.org) for all documentation.**